# How to use 'name' property in style object for 'react-native-vector-icons'?

Tags: react-native

icons can be used as `Text` by using `react-native-vector-icons` and styling as well can be done like `Text` as shown below,

```
<Icon name="phone" style={Style.iconStyle} />
const Styles = {
    iconStyle: {
       marginTop:7,
       marginRight: 10,
       fontSize:20
    }
}
```

if I use `name` property as well in style object, Following warning is being thrown,

```
Warning:Failed prop type: Invalid props.style key 'name' supplied to 'Text'.
```

is there any way to include `name` as well in style object?

Comment: What do you mean "use `name` property as well in style object"? Why would you want to do that?

Comment: No, name is the prop that defines which icon to display

Comment: No `name` property used in the style tag. you just need to use pass name of the icon you need to use in name props and style in style props. Please check link for more info https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons

Comment: @Ryan Turnbull-Thank you

Comment: @Nisarg Thakkar-Thank You